# How to use Google.Cloud.Speech.V1 of NuGet on Unity/C# for Android Device?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, nuget, google-cloud-speech

I would like to use Streaming Speech Recognition by Google Cloud Speech API on Unity/C#/Android.

I tried the following step.

### Environments & Install history

- macOS Sierra : 10.12.6
- Unity : 2017.2.0p1 Personal
- NuGet : 4.4.1.4638
- Google.Cloud.Speech.V1 : 1.0.0
- Android : 7.0
- Install history

  ```
  $ cd UNITY_ASSETS_PATH
  $ mkdir Goolge.Cloud.Speech.V1
  $ cd Goolge.Cloud.Speech.V1
  $ nuget install Google.Cloud.Speech.V1
  ```

### Errors

Open Unity Editor, these errors displayed in Unity Editor Console.

[displayed errors image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrQaA.png)

Please tell me if there is a way to solve this problem, or whether using Google.Cloud.Speech.V1 can be done on this situation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the libraries of the SDK define all these items twice. You may either:

- remove one of the folders under Assets/Google.Cloud.Speech.V1/Google.Api.CommonProtos.1.1.0/lib (the one that you will not need in the end, if you are using Android only then probably net45; if it does not work then try the other one)
- define how the libraries should be imported: in the Unity Editor, select the libraries (in the folder aforementionned) and assign them to a specific execution environment (the libraries in net45 for Standalone, the libraries in netstandard1.3 for the others)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  

Please teach where settings to me.  

> in the Unity Editor, select the libraries and assign them to a specific execution environment